# Perl: open or [block of code]?

Tags: perl

I'm running script A which feeds ARGV containing the path to a file to perl script B. This is done by a

```
local @ARGV = ($file, $file2, etc.);
do scriptB.pl or die "scriptB has failed";
```

Script B then tries to open the file:

```
open( my $fh_file, "<", $file )  
  or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";
```

However, if the file is missing I do not get the message quoted after "or die" in B. Instead I get the do scriptB.pl or die message in A. If I remove the "or die" from A, the script continues after B silently dies as if nothing went wrong.

I was wondering if there was any way to get B to print its die message?

Better yet, what is the best way to have B run a block of code after it fails to open the file? Said code would for example write to a separate file listing which files were missing so that the user may easily track down such errors.

```
#something like
open( my $fh_file, "<", $file) or { 
print "the file could not be found";
die;
}
```

The only thing I've found searching the net for help was someone mentioning a "or do {}", but this is giving me strange syntax errors so I am not sure if I'm using it right.

Comment: *"this is giving me strange syntax errors"* Please reveal what those strange errors are, and show the code that is producing them.

Comment: Note that you need a semicolon after the block in `open ... or do { ... };`

Comment: You need quotes around `scriptB.pl` (if you `use strict`, as you should) : `do "scriptB.pl" or do { if ( $@) { ... } else { die $! }};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to continue to use the `open(...) or ...` syntax, then you could use `do`.

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or do {
  ...
};
```

But I think it's probably clearer to switch to `if`

```
if (! open my $fh, '<', $file) {
  ...
}
```

Or even `unless`

```
unless (open my $fh '<', $file) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for presenting three very good options. I'm not  sure that the `or do {...}` syntax is less clear though, since it builds upon the common `or die` pattern that people have (Possibly? Hopefully?) grown accustomed to seeing.

Comment: Sure. Clarity is in the eye of the maintenance programmer :-) But at the very least there's a huge increase in the chance of syntax errors as people forget that closing semicolon.

Comment: Downvoting for accepting `or do { print(STDERR "...: $!\n"; die "ignored message"; };` as an acceptable alternative for `or die "...: $!\n"`. This approach shouldn't be taken!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get clearer code with fewer gotchas if you put script B into a module, and load it with `use` or `require` and call the function(s) in there directly with clear parameters.

What you're missing here is that `do` involves an `eval` behind the scenes, and that results in the exception confusion.  You can more or less avoid that confusion by moving your script B code into a function in a module, and calling it.

(Also, perl 5.26 will have a slight hiccup with `do` wherein the current directory will be removed from the directory lookup, due to security concerns.  `use` and `require` have the same hiccup, but this may be less surprising since you should put your module into a path you explicitly get into the `@INC` load path.)

Answer (score 1):

`die` doesn't print a message; `die` throws an exception. When you catch that exception you don't do anything with the message passed to `die`. Replace

```
local @ARGV = ($file, $file2, etc.);
do scriptB.pl or die "scriptB has failed";
```

with

```
local @ARGV = ($file, $file2, etc.);
do scriptB.pl or die "scriptB has failed: ". ( $@ || $! );
```